# Making multiple mysqli queries using a for loop

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to make a series of mysqli queries by looping through the values of an array - (called column) - but nothing is being returned.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($column); $i++)

{
    $mutualInterests = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT USER_1 FROM INTERESTS WHERE answer = " . $column[$i] );

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($mutualInterests))

    {
        echo " $row[USER_1]";

    }


}
```

Comment: Why not just use `in`?

Comment: It is more efficient using IN like this `"SELECT USER_1 FROM INTERESTS WHERE answer IN (" . implode(',', $column) . ")"`

Comment: Show example of `$column`

Comment: I wasn't aware 'in' was a thing. I must try that! 
@RiggsFolly 
'$column = array("music", "sports" ,"movies");'

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah, "IN" definitely works much better than what I was trying. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just replace your given code with following and see result ..........

```
$query='SELECT USER_1 FROM INTERESTS WHERE answer ="'.$column[0].'"';

for ($i = 1; $i < sizeof($column); $i++)

{
$query.=' OR answer ="'.$column[$i].'"';

}

$mutualInterests = mysqli_query ($conn,$query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($mutualInterests))

{
    echo " $row[USER_1]";

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($mutualInterests))

{
    echo " $row[USER_1]";

}
```

with this:

```
$count = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($mutualInterests))
{
    echo $row[$count]."<br>";
    $count++;

}
```

Let me know if it works now! :)

Comment: @ianmc i modified my answer, try now

Comment: @ianmc can you show us the result that you are getting with your code?

Comment: Nothing was being returned to my page I think. No result to show